# angularjs - send parameters with $compile

Tags: angularjs, view, compilation, scope, directive

I have created a directive `open`, I want to compile it and be able to access the scope inside my directive view.

```
$compile("<open data='scope'></open>")(scope)
```

Inside my view I tried to access `{{scope}}` or {{data}} but without success.

Any idea ?

Comment: show your directive definition, when you pass the scope object to the link function that's returned from the call to $compile it is assigned to $scope (passed into the link function).  The properties of $scope are accessible from the view by name but the $scope itself is not, would be good to see the properties of the object scope you are passing to the link function.

Comment: How are they related? because you can either transclude it or access the parent directive controller & scope.

Comment: What happened here? any answer?